# downloaded 13.04 on inspiron 3520, at start it gives me two icons windows and ubuntu, windows works great, ubuntu gives error message

Tags: installation, dual-boot

Recently downloaded Ubuntu 13.04 on my windows desktop. It downloaded and partitioned automatically, after restart, two icons emerged, for the dual boot one for windows 8 the other for Ubuntu, Windows icon works great and pulls up windows 8, the Ubuntu icon, is a little slow and then brings up this error message. "windows failed to start, a recent hardware change might be the problem" it continues on " insert windows reinstall, choose language then next click repair, if you don't have disc contact system admin file/Ubuntu/winboot/wubi/dr.mr, status Oxcooooo7b required file is missing or contains errors." this has done this for three different versions of Ubuntu I have tried to install 12.04, 12.10 and now 13.04. Is there something I am missing? I am dual booting, from desktop, not a cd, from some reason even when I boot from cd first it does not start.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on a Dell Inspiron 5720.  Are you booting in UEFI mode? Or Legacy?  If you are booting in UEFI mode, you may need to go into the BIOS (hold down F2 at the Dell boot screen) and go over to the Boot tab.  My laptop lists boot priority.  If Ubuntu isn't listed, go down to Add and select the Ubuntu partition, then go down to the file selection and look for the bootx64.efi file in the /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu.  (It has been a little bit since I did this.  And I can't edit my entry to see what I have selected.)  This may allow you to boot ubuntu.  It sounds like Ubuntu isn't passing secureboot, and the laptop is attempting to go to Windows by default.  I hope this will be of some help.